# Migrating VB6 code for printing on Dot Matrix Printer to VB.Net

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

I have VB6 code to print on dot matrix printer. It works very well but now I want to upgrade to VB.net. How can I adapt the same printing code to VB.net?

```
Close #1
        Open "output.txt" For Output As #1
        prntitle
        Set salinvrs = Nothing
        Set salinvrs = abazcn.Execute("select * from creditnote where INVOICENO = '" & txtinvno.Text & "' ORDER BY mfr")
        Do While salinvrs.EOF <> True
            If salinvrs(12) = 0 Then
                xtxt = "Inc"
            Else
                xtxt = Format(salinvrs(12), ".00")
            End If
            If salinvrs(26) <> 0 Then
                xtxt = xtxt & "-" & "#"
            End If
        If salinvrs(3) > 0 And xrow < 6 Then
           varretuqty = salinvrs(3) & ""
           varval = Val(salinvrs(3)) * Val(salinvrs(4))
            Print #1, Mid(salinvrs(17), 1, 5);
            Print #1, Space(7 - Len(Mid(salinvrs(17), 1, 5))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(2)), 1, 22);
            Print #1, Space(23 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(2)), 1, 22))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(16)), 1, 5);
            Print #1, Space(7 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(16)), 1, 5))); Format(Val(salinvrs(19)), "00.00");
            Print #1, Space(8 - Len(Format(Val(salinvrs(19)), "00.00"))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(11)), 1, 6);
            Print #1, Space(8 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(11)), 1, 6))); salinvrs(13);
            Print #1, Space(10 - Len(salinvrs(13))); Format(Val(salinvrs(4)), "00.00");
            Print #1, Space(7 - Len(salinvrs(3) & "+" & salinvrs(14))); salinvrs(3) & "+" & salinvrs(14);
            Print #1, Space(9 - Len(Format(varval, ".00"))); Format(varval, ".00");
            Print #1, Space(6 - Len(xtxt)); xtxt;
            Print #1, Space(10 - Len(Format(salinvrs(5), ".00"))); Format(salinvrs(5), ".00")
        End If
        If xrow = 6 Then
                varval = Val(salinvrs(3)) * Val(salinvrs(4))
                Print #1, Mid(salinvrs(17), 1, 5);
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(Mid(salinvrs(17), 1, 5))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(2)), 1, 22);
                Print #1, Space(23 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(2)), 1, 22))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(16)), 1, 5);
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(16)), 1, 5))); Format(Val(salinvrs(19)), "00.00");
                Print #1, Space(8 - Len(Format(Val(salinvrs(19)), "00.00"))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(11)), 1, 6);
                Print #1, Space(8 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(11)), 1, 6))); salinvrs(13);
                Print #1, Space(10 - Len(salinvrs(13))); Format(Val(salinvrs(4)), "00.00");
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(salinvrs(3) & "+" & salinvrs(14))); salinvrs(3) & "+" & salinvrs(14);
                Print #1, Space(9 - Len(Format(varval, ".00"))); Format(varval, ".00");
                Print #1, Space(6 - Len(xtxt)); xtxt;
                Print #1, Space(10 - Len(Format(salinvrs(5), ".00"))); Format(salinvrs(5), ".00"); Space(15); txtinvno.Text
        End If
        If xrow = 7 Then
                varval = Val(salinvrs(3)) * Val(salinvrs(4))
                Print #1, Mid(salinvrs(17), 1, 5);
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(Mid(salinvrs(17), 1, 5))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(2)), 1, 22);
                Print #1, Space(23 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(2)), 1, 22))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(16)), 1, 5);
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(16)), 1, 5))); Format(Val(salinvrs(19)), "00.00");
                Print #1, Space(8 - Len(Format(Val(salinvrs(19)), "00.00"))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(11)), 1, 6);
                Print #1, Space(8 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(11)), 1, 6))); salinvrs(13);
                Print #1, Space(10 - Len(salinvrs(13))); Format(Val(salinvrs(4)), "00.00");
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(salinvrs(3) & "+" & salinvrs(14))); salinvrs(3) & "+" & salinvrs(14);
                Print #1, Space(9 - Len(Format(varval, ".00"))); Format(varval, ".00");
                Print #1, Space(6 - Len(xtxt)); xtxt;
                Print #1, Space(10 - Len(Format(salinvrs(5), ".00"))); Format(salinvrs(5), ".00"); Space(15); Me.dtbilldate.Value
         End If
         If xrow = 8 Then
                varval = Val(salinvrs(3)) * Val(salinvrs(4))
                Print #1, Mid(salinvrs(17), 1, 5);
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(Mid(salinvrs(17), 1, 5))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(2)), 1, 22);
                Print #1, Space(23 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(2)), 1, 22))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(16)), 1, 5);
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(16)), 1, 5))); Format(Val(salinvrs(19)), "00.00");
                Print #1, Space(8 - Len(Format(Val(salinvrs(19)), "00.00"))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(11)), 1, 6);
                Print #1, Space(8 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(11)), 1, 6))); salinvrs(13);
                Print #1, Space(10 - Len(salinvrs(13))); Format(Val(salinvrs(4)), "00.00");
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(salinvrs(3) & "+" & salinvrs(14))); salinvrs(3) & "+" & salinvrs(14);
                Print #1, Space(9 - Len(Format(varval, ".00"))); Format(varval, ".00");
                Print #1, Space(6 - Len(xtxt)); xtxt;
                Print #1, Space(10 - Len(Format(salinvrs(5), ".00"))); Format(salinvrs(5), ".00"); Space(15); Format(txttotamo.Text, "#,##,###.00")
        End If
        If xrow = 9 Then
                varval = Val(salinvrs(3)) * Val(salinvrs(4))
                Print #1, Mid(salinvrs(17), 1, 5);
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(Mid(salinvrs(17), 1, 5))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(2)), 1, 22);
                Print #1, Space(23 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(2)), 1, 22))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(16)), 1, 5);
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(16)), 1, 5))); Format(Val(salinvrs(19)), "00.00");
                Print #1, Space(8 - Len(Format(Val(salinvrs(19)), "00.00"))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(11)), 1, 6);
                Print #1, Space(8 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(11)), 1, 6))); salinvrs(13);
                Print #1, Space(10 - Len(salinvrs(13))); Format(Val(salinvrs(4)), "00.00");
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(salinvrs(3) & "+" & salinvrs(14))); salinvrs(3) & "+" & salinvrs(14);
                Print #1, Space(9 - Len(Format(varval, ".00"))); Format(varval, ".00");
                Print #1, Space(6 - Len(xtxt)); xtxt;
                Print #1, Space(10 - Len(Format(salinvrs(5), ".00"))); Format(salinvrs(5), ".00"); Space(15); Format(txttotal.Text, "#,##,###.00")
            End If
        If xrow = 10 Then
                varval = Val(salinvrs(3)) * Val(salinvrs(4))
                Print #1, Mid(salinvrs(17), 1, 5);
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(Mid(salinvrs(17), 1, 5))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(2)), 1, 22);
                Print #1, Space(23 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(2)), 1, 22))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(16)), 1, 5);
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(16)), 1, 5))); Format(Val(salinvrs(19)), "00.00");
                Print #1, Space(8 - Len(Format(Val(salinvrs(19)), "00.00"))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(11)), 1, 6);
                Print #1, Space(8 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(11)), 1, 6))); salinvrs(13);
                Print #1, Space(10 - Len(salinvrs(13))); Format(Val(salinvrs(4)), "00.00");
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(salinvrs(3) & "+" & salinvrs(14))); salinvrs(3) & "+" & salinvrs(14);
                Print #1, Space(9 - Len(Format(varval, ".00"))); Format(varval, ".00");
                Print #1, Space(6 - Len(xtxt)); xtxt;
                Print #1, Space(10 - Len(Format(salinvrs(5), ".00"))); Format(salinvrs(5), ".00"); Space(15); Format(txtdisc.Text, "#,###.00")
            End If
        If xrow = 11 Then
                varval = Val(salinvrs(3)) * Val(salinvrs(4))
                Print #1, Mid(salinvrs(17), 1, 5);
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(Mid(salinvrs(17), 1, 5))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(2)), 1, 22);
                Print #1, Space(23 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(2)), 1, 22))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(16)), 1, 5);
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(16)), 1, 5))); Format(Val(salinvrs(19)), "00.00");
                Print #1, Space(8 - Len(Format(Val(salinvrs(19)), "00.00"))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(11)), 1, 6);
                Print #1, Space(8 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(11)), 1, 6))); salinvrs(13);
                Print #1, Space(10 - Len(salinvrs(13))); Format(Val(salinvrs(4)), "00.00");
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(salinvrs(3) & "+" & salinvrs(14))); salinvrs(3) & "+" & salinvrs(14);
                Print #1, Space(9 - Len(Format(varval, ".00"))); Format(varval, ".00");
                Print #1, Space(6 - Len(xtxt)); xtxt;
                Print #1, Space(10 - Len(Format(salinvrs(5), ".00"))); Format(salinvrs(5), ".00"); Space(15); txtdiscper.Text; " "; "%"
        End If
        If xrow = 12 Then
                varval = Val(salinvrs(3)) * Val(salinvrs(4))
                Print #1, Mid(salinvrs(17), 1, 5);
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(Mid(salinvrs(17), 1, 5))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(2)), 1, 22);
                Print #1, Space(23 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(2)), 1, 22))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(16)), 1, 5);
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(16)), 1, 5))); Format(Val(salinvrs(19)), "00.00");
                Print #1, Space(8 - Len(Format(Val(salinvrs(19)), "00.00"))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(11)), 1, 6);
                Print #1, Space(8 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(11)), 1, 6))); salinvrs(13);
                Print #1, Space(10 - Len(salinvrs(13))); Format(Val(salinvrs(4)), "00.00");
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(salinvrs(3) & "+" & salinvrs(14))); salinvrs(3) & "+" & salinvrs(14);
                Print #1, Space(9 - Len(Format(varval, ".00"))); Format(varval, ".00");
                Print #1, Space(6 - Len(xtxt)); xtxt;
                Print #1, Space(10 - Len(Format(salinvrs(5), ".00"))); Format(salinvrs(5), ".00"); Space(15); Me.txtmiscadd.Text & "/" & Me.txtmiscless.Text
        End If
        If xrow = 13 Then
                varval = Val(salinvrs(3)) * Val(salinvrs(4))
                Print #1, Mid(salinvrs(17), 1, 5);
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(Mid(salinvrs(17), 1, 5))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(2)), 1, 22);
                Print #1, Space(23 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(2)), 1, 22))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(16)), 1, 5);
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(16)), 1, 5))); Format(Val(salinvrs(19)), "00.00");
                Print #1, Space(8 - Len(Format(Val(salinvrs(19)), "00.00"))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(11)), 1, 6);
                Print #1, Space(8 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(11)), 1, 6))); salinvrs(13);
                Print #1, Space(10 - Len(salinvrs(13))); Format(Val(salinvrs(4)), "00.00");
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(salinvrs(3) & "+" & salinvrs(14))); salinvrs(3) & "+" & salinvrs(14);
                Print #1, Space(9 - Len(Format(varval, ".00"))); Format(varval, ".00");
                Print #1, Space(6 - Len(xtxt)); xtxt;
                Print #1, Space(10 - Len(Format(salinvrs(5), ".00"))); Format(salinvrs(5), ".00"); Space(15); Me.txtrst.Text
            End If
        If xrow = 14 Then
                varval = Val(salinvrs(3)) * Val(salinvrs(4))
                Print #1, Mid(salinvrs(17), 1, 5);
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(Mid(salinvrs(17), 1, 5))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(2)), 1, 22);
                Print #1, Space(23 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(2)), 1, 22))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(16)), 1, 5);
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(16)), 1, 5))); Format(Val(salinvrs(19)), "00.00");
                Print #1, Space(8 - Len(Format(Val(salinvrs(19)), "00.00"))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(11)), 1, 6);
                Print #1, Space(8 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(11)), 1, 6))); salinvrs(13);
                Print #1, Space(10 - Len(salinvrs(13))); Format(Val(salinvrs(4)), "00.00");
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(salinvrs(3) & "+" & salinvrs(14))); salinvrs(3) & "+" & salinvrs(14);
                Print #1, Space(9 - Len(Format(varval, ".00"))); Format(varval, ".00");
                Print #1, Space(6 - Len(xtxt)); xtxt;
                Print #1, Space(10 - Len(Format(salinvrs(5), ".00"))); Format(salinvrs(5), ".00"); Space(15); Me.txtcrnote.Text
            End If
        If xrow = 15 Then
                varval = Val(salinvrs(3)) * Val(salinvrs(4))
                Print #1, Mid(salinvrs(17), 1, 5);
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(Mid(salinvrs(17), 1, 5))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(2)), 1, 22);
                Print #1, Space(23 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(2)), 1, 22))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(16)), 1, 5);
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(16)), 1, 5))); Format(Val(salinvrs(19)), "00.00");
                Print #1, Space(8 - Len(Format(Val(salinvrs(19)), "00.00"))); Mid(Trim(salinvrs(11)), 1, 6);
                Print #1, Space(8 - Len(Mid(Trim(salinvrs(11)), 1, 6))); salinvrs(13);
                Print #1, Space(10 - Len(salinvrs(13))); Format(Val(salinvrs(4)), "00.00");
                Print #1, Space(7 - Len(salinvrs(3) & "+" & salinvrs(14))); salinvrs(3) & "+" & salinvrs(14);
                Print #1, Space(9 - Len(Format(varval, ".00"))); Format(varval, ".00");
                Print #1, Space(6 - Len(xtxt)); xtxt;
                Print #1, Space(10 - Len(Format(salinvrs(5), ".00"))); Format(salinvrs(5), ".00"); Space(15); Me.txtnetamo.Text
            End If
        yrow = yrow + 1
        salinvrs.MoveNext
        xrow = xrow + 1
        If xrow = 16 Then
            Print #1,
            Print #1,
            Print #1, Space(69); "CONTINUE.. .. .. .. PAGE :"; Space(3); varpage
            For i = 1 To 6
                Print #1,
            Next i
            prntitle
            xrow = 0
            i = 0
            varpage = varpage + 1
         End If
      Loop

         If xrow < 15 Then
            For i = 1 To (15 - xrow)
            Next i
                If i = 16 And varpage >= 1 Then
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtinvno.Text
                    Print #1, Space(115); Me.dtbilldate.Value
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txttotal.Text, "#,##,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txttotamo.Text, "#,##,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txtdisc.Text, "#,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); txtdiscper.Text & " " & "%"
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtmiscadd.Text & "/" & Me.txtmiscless.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtrst.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtcrnote.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtnetamo.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116);
                    Print #1,
                    prnbottomval
                End If

                If i = 15 And varpage >= 1 Then
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtinvno.Text
                    Print #1, Space(115); Me.dtbilldate.Value
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txttotal.Text, "#,##,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txttotamo.Text, "#,##,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txtdisc.Text, "#,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); txtdiscper.Text & " " & "%"
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtmiscadd.Text & "/" & Me.txtmiscless.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtrst.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtcrnote.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtnetamo.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116);
                    Print #1,
                    prnbottomval
                End If
                If i = 14 And varpage >= 1 Then
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtinvno.Text
                    Print #1, Space(115); Me.dtbilldate.Value
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txttotal.Text, "#,##,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txttotamo.Text, "#,##,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txtdisc.Text, "#,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); txtdiscper.Text & " " & "%"
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtmiscadd.Text & "/" & Me.txtmiscless.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtrst.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtcrnote.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtnetamo.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116);
                    Print #1,
                    prnbottomval
                End If
                If i = 13 And varpage >= 1 Then
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtinvno.Text
                    Print #1, Space(115); Me.dtbilldate.Value
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txttotal.Text, "#,##,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txttotamo.Text, "#,##,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txtdisc.Text, "#,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); txtdiscper.Text & " " & "%"
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtmiscadd.Text & "/" & Me.txtmiscless.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtrst.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtcrnote.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtnetamo.Text
                    Print #1,
                    prnbottomval
                End If
                If i = 12 And varpage >= 1 Then
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtinvno.Text
                    Print #1, Space(115); Me.dtbilldate.Value
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txttotal.Text, "#,##,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txttotamo.Text, "#,##,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txtdisc.Text, "#,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); txtdiscper.Text & " " & "%"
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtmiscadd.Text & "/" & Me.txtmiscless.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtrst.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtcrnote.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtnetamo.Text
                    Print #1,
                    prnbottomval
                End If
                If i = 11 And varpage >= 1 Then
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtinvno.Text
                    Print #1, Space(115); Me.dtbilldate.Value
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txttotal.Text, "#,##,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txttotamo.Text, "#,##,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txtdisc.Text, "#,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); txtdiscper.Text & " " & "%"
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtmiscadd.Text & "/" & Me.txtmiscless.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtrst.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtcrnote.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtnetamo.Text
                    Print #1,
                    prnbottomval
                End If
                If i = 10 And varpage >= 1 Then
                    Print #1,
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtinvno.Text
                    Print #1, Space(115); Me.dtbilldate.Value
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txttotal.Text, "#,##,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txttotamo.Text, "#,##,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txtdisc.Text, "#,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); txtdiscper.Text & " " & "%"
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtmiscadd.Text & "/" & Me.txtmiscless.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtrst.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtcrnote.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtnetamo.Text
                    Print #1,
                    prnbottomval
                End If
                If i = 9 And varpage >= 1 Then
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtinvno.Text
                    Print #1, Space(115); Me.dtbilldate.Value
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txttotal.Text, "#,##,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txttotamo.Text, "#,##,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txtdisc.Text, "#,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); txtdiscper.Text & " " & "%"
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtmiscadd.Text & "/" & Me.txtmiscless.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtrst.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtcrnote.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtnetamo.Text
                    Print #1,
                    prnbottomval
                End If
                If i = 8 And varpage >= 1 Then
                    Print #1, Space(115); Me.dtbilldate.Value
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txttotal.Text, "#,##,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txttotamo.Text, "#,##,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txtdisc.Text, "#,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); txtdiscper.Text & " " & "%"
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtmiscadd.Text & "/" & Me.txtmiscless.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtrst.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtcrnote.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtnetamo.Text
                    Print #1,
                    prnbottomval
                End If
                If i = 7 And varpage >= 1 Then
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txttotal.Text, "#,##,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txttotamo.Text, "#,##,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txtdisc.Text, "#,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); txtdiscper.Text & " " & "%"
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtmiscadd.Text & "/" & Me.txtmiscless.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtrst.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtcrnote.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtnetamo.Text
                    Print #1,
                    prnbottomval
                End If
                If i = 6 And varpage >= 1 Then
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txttotamo.Text, "#,##,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txtdisc.Text, "#,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); txtdiscper.Text & " " & "%"
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtmiscadd.Text & "/" & Me.txtmiscless.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtrst.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtcrnote.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtnetamo.Text
                    Print #1,
                    prnbottomval
                End If
                If i = 5 And varpage >= 1 Then
                    Print #1, Space(116); Format(txtdisc.Text, "#,###.00")
                    Print #1, Space(116); txtdiscper.Text & " " & "%"
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtmiscadd.Text & "/" & Me.txtmiscless.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtrst.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtcrnote.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtnetamo.Text
                    Print #1,
                    prnbottomval
                End If
                If i = 4 And varpage >= 1 Then
                    Print #1, Space(116); txtdiscper.Text & " " & "%"
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtmiscadd.Text & "/" & Me.txtmiscless.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtrst.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtcrnote.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtnetamo.Text
                    Print #1,
                    prnbottomval
                End If
                If i = 3 And varpage >= 1 Then
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtmiscadd.Text & "/" & Me.txtmiscless.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtrst.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtcrnote.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtnetamo.Text
                    Print #1,
                    prnbottomval
                End If
                If i = 2 And varpage >= 1 Then
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtrst.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtcrnote.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtnetamo.Text
                    Print #1,
                    prnbottomval
                End If
                If i = 1 And varpage >= 1 Then
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtcrnote.Text
                    Print #1, Space(116); Me.txtnetamo.Text
                    Print #1,
                    prnbottomval
                End If
        End If
    Close #1
    Open "output.bat" For Output As #1
    Print #1, "type output.txt>prn"
    Close #1
    Shell "output.bat", vbHide

    Private Sub prntitle()
Print #1,
Print #1,
Print #1, Space(50); "CREDIT NOTE"
        Print #1,
        Print #1,
        Print #1, Mid(Trim(txtcrdcustname.Text), 1, 35); Space(52 - Len(Mid(Trim(txtcrdcustname.Text), 1, 35))); Trim(txttngstno.Text); Space(26 - Len(Trim(txttngstno.Text))); cboinvno.Text
        Print #1, Trim(txtadd2.Text); Space(52 - Len(Mid(Trim(txtadd2.Text), 1, 40))); Trim(txtdlno1.Text); Space(26 - Len(Trim(txtdlno1.Text))); dtbilldate.Value
        Print #1, Mid(Trim(txtcustadd.Text), 1, 25); Space(36 - Len(Mid(Trim(txtcustadd.Text), 1, 25))); Space(18); Trim(Me.txtdlno2.Text); Space(26 - Len(Trim(txtdlno2.Text)))
        Print #1, Trim(Me.txtadd3.Text); Space(78 - Len(Mid(Trim(txtadd3.Text), 1, 15)))
        Print #1, Trim(Me.txtadd4.Text); Space(78 - Len(Mid(Trim(Me.txtadd4.Text), 1, 15)))
        Print #1,
        Print #1,

End Sub
Private Sub prnbottomval()
        Print #1, Space(13)
        Print #1, Space(5); Format(txttotal.Text, "#,##0.00"); Space(11 - Len(Format(txttotal.Text, "#,##0.00"))); Format(txttotamo.Text, "#,###.00"); Space(14 - Len(Format(txttotamo.Text, "#,##0.00"))); Format(txtdisc.Text, "#,##0.00"); _
                  Space(16 - Len(Format(txtdisc.Text, "#,##0.00"))); Format(txtmiscadd.Text, "0.00"); _
                  Space(6 - Len(Format(txtmiscadd.Text, "#,##0.00"))); Format(txtmiscless.Text, "0.00"); _
                  Space(13 - Len(Format(txtmiscless.Text, "#,##0.00"))); Format(txtrst.Text, "0.00"); _
                  Space(12 - Len(Format(txtrst.Text, "0.00"))); Format((0 - Val(txtcrnote.Text)), "0.00"); _
                  Space(13 - Len(Format((0 - Val(txtcrnote.Text)), "0.00"))); Format(txtnetamo.Text, "#,##0.00")
        Print #1,
        Print #1, "("; lblamount.Caption; Space(1); ")"
        Print #1,
        Print #1,
        Print #1,
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the actual code instead of a screenshot. That way we can try running the code on our end and help you out.

Comment: Hi, have tried the VB 2005 Express Edition ? It contains a converter that is not perfect but it should be a good start.

Comment: First question: Do you still need to print to the matrix printer? Second question: Did you ever see the VB6 printer object? Third question: Did you already print with VB.NET printing system? Fourth question: Are you aware there is an "VB6 Printer like object" available for .NET? (Something with the Microsoft Visual Basic DLL ...)

Comment: nabuchodonossor : Thank you for your response, first question answer is YES, why bec I am having own medical store so for pharma field rules not allowing to print on thermal printer or other laser printers. So I must to use Dot Matrix printer. 2nd Q: I am new to vb.net so I need help from you. if you are tell me the way in details please. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to modify some of your code but a good part of it should work fairly easily in VB.net.

First things will be to replace the file you are opening to a StreamWriter:

```
Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("output.txt", True)
```

Then, instead of all those `Print #1` statements, take everything that comes after `Print #1,` and put it inside `file.WriteLine( )`:

```
file.WriteLine(Mid(salinvrs(17), 1, 5))
```

When you are done writing to the file, use:

```
file.Close()
```

As far as your Recordset is concerned, to keep things simple for now, you can keep using ADO (you will need to add a Reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects in COM tab). You should consider upgrading your code to use ADO.NET. There are many examples of how to read a DataSet, here's one:

[Create a simple data application by using ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-simple-data-application-by-using-adonet?view=vs-2019)

[Using the ADO and Recordset in VB.NET](http://checktechno.blogspot.com/2013/04/using-ado-and-recordset-in-vbnet.html)

Comment: file.WriteLine(Space(10), "Patient Name", Mid(Trim(txtsname.Text), 1, 35), Space(52 - Len(Mid(Trim(txtsname.Text), 1, 35))), Space(10), "S.InvoiceNo :", txtsalinvno.Text)
                file.WriteLine(Space(10), "Doctor Name", Mid(Trim(cbodoctors.Text), 1, 35), Space(52 - Len(Mid(Trim(cbodoctors.Text), 1, 35))), Space(10), "Inv.Date :", Trim(txtinvdte.Text))

Comment: I Tried this above code but output.txt file is empty

Comment: Please update your question with your updated code. Posting code in comments is difficult to read.

Comment: Looking at the code in your comment though, I don't think you can concatenate strings like that (using commas). You can use `file.Write` multiple times and then end your line: `file.Write Space(10)` then `file.Write "Patient Name"` then `file.Write Mid(Trim(txtsname.Text), 1, 35)`, etc. Finally, to finish the line, you can use `file.Write vbCrLf`

Comment: Thanks brother, How can I change font size for title and underline and lines

Comment: That's a whole different question, you can post a new question for that. There was no font sizing and formatting in your original question. You can probably do this using printer control codes but if you post a new question, more people who are knowledgeable about this might see it and answer. You can also check your printer's operation manual, these codes are probably listed in there.